# Inheritance In Java [error when sub class declared as protected]

Tags: java, inheritance, compiler-errors, protected

Confusing:

- protected modifier uses mainly in inheritance mechanism protected we can extend
- coming to privileges if super is more restrictive (private) in sub classes might be less

  ```
  public class Sub extends Base //line 1
  {
    Sub()
     {
          System.out.println("Base Class");
     }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
            System.out.println("Calling From Main");
            Base b = new Base()
            Sub s = new Sub();
      }
  }
  protected class Base        // line 14
  {
    Base()
      {
          System.out.println("Base Class");
      }
  }
  ```
- compilation files at line 14

  ```
  error: modifier protected not allowed here
  protected class Base
            ^
  1 error
  ```
- why it gives error please explain ?
- Is it possible to declare/extend protected classes ?

Comment: classes can't be protected. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

**Protected** and **Private** classes are allowed only as inner and nested classes.
In inheritance, **Protected** is used as method or variable level, not for top class level.